# Struggling with understanding NetGraph result

Tags: neural-networks

I am novice in Neural Networks and particularly with its implementation in Mathematica. I am trying to understand the graphical result of NetGraph function but it results in non-classical displaying of ANN - representation is linear, but I expect to see layers and neurons, like on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRZ6z.png).

How should I interpret the result of NetGraph visual output and how to build e.g. XOR neural network as on the image above?

Comment: The idea as I understand it is to imitate what tensorflow does: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs

Comment: Modern deep neural networks often have millions of neurons and weights (e.g. for each pixel in an image) - so it isn't practical to draw each neuron individually. Instead, you draw layers of neurons that perform the same function, like dot product or convolution

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to understand the graphical result of NetGraph function but it results in non-classical displaying of ANN

The image you sent is not of a NetGraph, but rather a chain: `NetChain[{LinearLayer[2], LinearLayer[1]}]`. It would be simple to write your own visualizer for this similar to the image you sent, but we don't have built-in functionality for this. The reason: its super-specific to the `LinearLayer` (how do convolutions look? or attention layers? or...). Basically, this style of graph is only interesting for tiny toy nets composed of LinearLayers.